# anchorScroll it does not work correctly

Tags: angularjs, anchor-scroll

I'm having a problem with `anchorScroll`, I run a list with ng-repeat that as id has a timeStamp date, when I identify the id I want the scroll to go to it, it takes me correctly, but for some reason the scroll The rest of my sight is lost.

```
$scope.scrollTo = function (elementId) {
    $location.hash(elementId);
    $anchorScroll();
    $ionicScrollDelegate.resize();
};
```